# Happy Venndredi! A Nicer Team Diet?

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

Bonjour

The overlapping ellipses form seven curved regions. Your task is to place the seven tiles so that there is exactly one tile in each region and the four tiles in any ellipse can be re-arranged to form an eight-letter solution to the corresponding clue!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resolved Venn diagram should look like this:

> [image: Resolved Venn diagram]

The clues can be interpreted as follows:

> "SONG PIE?" = **AMERICAN** (i.e. *[American Pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Pie_(song))*, the 1971 song by Don McLean).
>
>  "SHINY MATERIAL" = **DIAMANTE**, a [glittering ornament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamante), like an artificial jewel or sequin.
>
>  "R & R?" = **DIAMETER**, since the diameter ('d') of a circle is the length of two radii, each usually abbreviated to 'r' (so $d = r + r$).

Comment: As ever well done!